# How to get spark dataframes from grouped data

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe, and I want to group by a column and turn the groups back into dataframes with the same schema. The reason is that I want to map a function with signature `DataFrame -> String` across the groups. Here is what I'm trying:

```
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq((1,2,3),(1,2,4),(2,3,4))).toDF
val schema = df.schema
val groups = df.rdd.groupBy(x => x(0))
               .mapValues(g => sqlContext.createDataFrame(sc.makeRDD(g.toList), schema))
               .take(1)
```

Here's what I'm hoping for:

```
scala> groups(0)._2.collect
Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([1,2,3], [1,2,4])
```

but it's not working (the tasks are failing with `NullPointerException`) ... I guess you cant map a function that refers to the spark context, but i'm not sure how else to achieve this?

Comment: can you provide an example.
What input and output you are expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I guess you cant map a function that refers to the spark context

Correct - you can't use any of Spark's context objects (or RDDs, or Dataframes) inside a function passed to any of Spark's higher-order functions, as that would require *serializing* these objects and sending them to the executors, but they are intentionally not serializable, because it wouldn't make sense (each executor would then have to behave like another driver application).

To achieve a Dataframe containing only one "group", I'd recommend using `filter` instead of `groupBy`: You can first `collect` all the group keys, then map each one to a filtered Dataframe:

```
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq((1,2,3),(1,2,4),(2,3,4))).toDF

df.cache() // EDIT: this might speed this up significantly, as DF will be reused instead of recalculated for each key 

val groupKeys: Array[Int] = df.map { case Row(i: Int, _, _) => i }.distinct().collect()
val dfPerKey: Array[DataFrame] = groupKeys.map(k => df.filter($"_1" === k))

dfPerKey.foreach(_.show())
// prints:
//    +---+---+---+
//    | _1| _2| _3|
//    +---+---+---+
//    |  1|  2|  3|
//    |  1|  2|  4|
//    +---+---+---+
//
//    +---+---+---+
//    | _1| _2| _3|
//    +---+---+---+
//    |  2|  3|  4|
//    +---+---+---+
```

Comment: Hi Tzach, thanks for takin the time to answer. This is a clever approach, unfortunately it's really slow, I think it's doing a full shuffle for each filter (for my large dataframe, it's running a separate stage for each group! any idea how to get something closer to the performance of `groupBy`?

Comment: Might help if you add `df.cache()` before collecting the keys and iterating over them.

Comment: Thanks Tzach, that fixed it ! thanks for you patience, i'm still very new to spark!